# Java crash when freeing intbuffer

Tags: java, crash, buffer, lwjgl

Whenever I run the following code java returns an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when freeing the IntBuffer:

```
public int[] size(){
    IntBuffer size=BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
    long address=MemoryUtil.memAddress(size);

    GLFW.nglfwGetWindowSize(this.handle, address, address+Integer.BYTES);
    int[] result=new int[]{size.get(0), size.get(1)};

    JEmalloc.nje_free(address);

    return result;
}
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/unZTvsY2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ByteBuffer` created by `BufferUtils` will be released by the garbage collector when there's no more references to it.

If you want to use `JEmalloc.nje_free()` to free the buffer, then you also need to use `JEmalloc` when allocating the buffer.

```
IntBuffer size = JEmalloc.je_malloc(2 * Integer.BYTES).asIntBuffer();
long address = MemoryUtil.memAddress(size);

[...]

JEmalloc.nje_free(address);
```